# How to create an Eclipse plug-in including non binary files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create an Eclipse plug-in to make a Papyrus model available to the Workspace. The goal is to provide the user a simple way to refer to that model in hers/his own models. I tried to produce such plug-in by including the model files in a new plug-in project, setting up the extension points [referred here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/604098/); but later on, when the plug-in is included, the model is nowhere to be found.

In the past I was able to create plug-ins that add buttons or context menus, but not something that simply makes resources available. Is it possible? How?

Thank you.

**Update**: the contents of *plugin.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.dynamic_package">
      <resource
            uri="test.profile.plugin.resource1">
      </resource>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.uml2.uml.dynamic_package">
      <profile
            uri="test.profile.plugin.profile1">
      </profile>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.extensionpoints.UMLProfile">
      <profile
            name="test.profile.plugin.profile1"
            path="test.profile.plugin.profile1">
      </profile>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Comment: You are probably missing entries in the `build.properties` for the resources. This file must list everything that is to be included in the plug-in.

Comment: Thanks Greg, in the `build.properties` file I can mark the model files to include. This way the model is registered when the plug-in is installed, but it is unusable. I must still be missing something.

Comment: Add your plugin.xml in the question, maybe we can see something